# AngularJS's ng-model binding clarification?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> `ng-model`  binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control)
>   to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created
>   and exposed by this directive.

But looking at this simple code [**here**](http://jsbin.com/EREgUWU/3/edit) raise 2 questions :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     Name: <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.name.aaa.lalala"/><input type='button' value='done'/>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <div>
         Welcome, {{ctrl.name.aaa.lalala}}
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function MainCtrl($scope) {}
</script>
```

Visual :

[image]

**Questions**

1) Every time I change the input value - it's automatically changes the scope property. I believe it's how it works. But what if I want to accept the data only **after** pressing the button ? one solution is to put a flag into the scope : `"isPressed"` but I think it's *very wrong*.How can I change my code to do that ?

2)How come `ng-model="ctrl.name.aaa.lalala"` is working ? *I was hoping to get an exception* . **why**?

Becuase I learnd that I should do :

```
$scope.name={};
$scope.name.aaa={};
```

And then It would work.

But it works like this *without* predefining objects. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like Khanh TO's answer but here's a different solution that works well when you have a form with a number of properties that you may or may not want to use to update the model.

Say you had a form to update personal details of an individual where a person is represented by this model:

```
{
    firstname: 'wackford',
    lastname: 'squeers',
    phone: '1234 567890'
}
```

and your model contains a number of these:

```
$scope.users = [ {}, {}, {} ];
```

When you start editing a user you would copy the user to edit to another scope property e.g.

```
$scope.userUnderEdit =  angular.copy( $scope.user[0] );
```

If you press commit on the UI you would copy the edited user back to the users collection:

```
$scope.commitUserChanges = function(){
    $scope.users[0] = angular.copy( $scope.usersUnderEdit );
    // persist data etc.
}
```

If the user cancels the edit then just clear the userUnderEdit:

```
$scope.cancelUserChanges = function(){
    $scope.usersUnderEdit = null;
}
```

Demo: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/pKP4U/19/)</kbd>

Comment: A lot of places? A UserEditController would only need 3 references to the user under edit; select the user, commit the change and cancel the change. Easy on the eye and easily testable.

Comment: can u provide please jsfiddle ? I didnt succeed making it work :-(

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible that the title of editing will relate to the old value of person ? ( I dont want to edit the person and see it changes in the title)...

Comment: Have added an extra scope property, editUser, that references the user from the users list which is being edited. The reason I did it the other way initially was to show how the model for the edited user was changed but not the user in the users collection (until save was pressed).

Answer (score 2):

1) I would create a custom directive like this to hold the uncommitted value and only commit it when the button is clicked:

```
 app.directive("commitableValue",function(){
     return {
      require: '^ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        var committed; 
        var committedValue;

        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value){
          return committed ? value : committedValue; //return uncommitted value to the pipeline if the button is not clicked
        });

        scope.$watch(function(){ //Whenever ngModel.$modelValue changes, reset the values. This also deals with the case when another code updates the same property.
          return ngModel.$modelValue;
        },function (value){
          committedValue = ngModel.$modelValue; 
          committed = false;
        });

        scope.$on("commitValue",function(event){ 
          committed = true; //when receiving an event to commit the value, update the underlying model's property
          ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$viewValue);
        });

      }
    };
  });
```

Then apply this directive on fields that you need to save after the button is clicked:

```
<input type="text" commitable-value ng-model="ctrl.name.aaa.lalala"/>
```

When the button is clicked, we broadcast an event to notify all directives to commit its value:

```
<input type='button' value='done' ng-click="commitValue()"/>
```

JS:

```
$scope.commitValue = function(){
     $scope.$broadcast("commitValue");
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OMoCIkEB/6/edit)

2) `ng-model` will automatically create the property for you **after the first time** you change the value if the property is not defined. From the second time on, the property already exists, angular will just update the value.

Comment: can u please have alook at the second que4stion also ?

Comment: regarding 2 , so why people warned me that I could get property of undefined ? can u please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: @Royi Namir: if you do not enter anything, ng-model will not create the property, ng-model creates it only after the first time you enter something.

Comment: What do you mean "after the first time" ?  what about second time I change the value ? how is it different ? it is the same property. I dont understand why it is different.

Comment: For the second question look how Angular creates property for you if it's not set: [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/2068d767cfdc9662ece1495d39168a90dfcea174/src/ng/parse.js#L845)

Comment: _committedValuea is not defined_ in the jsfiddle console.

Comment: @Royi Namir: there was a mistake, check updated answer

Comment: @Royi Namir: from the second time, because the property already exists, angular will just update it